# Extract Values from a field

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I need to extract the whole value from a field

I have tried different Regex patterns and it did not work and was wondering if there was a simple way to do this.

Here's an example Splunk Event

```
HelloSample=My tool is too picky and has a hard time
```

Here's my splunk query

```
fields  HelloSample
```

This returns

```
My
```

I want it to return the whole string like below

```
My tool is too picky and has a hard time
```

Comment: *"I have tried different Regex patterns and it did not work".* Do you mind sharing those patterns with us, along with actual and expected behaviors?

Comment: Share some sample data, please - especially *where* in the event your expected text is

Answer (score 0):

There are [answers out there that involve doing some pretty intense regexes](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/438841/how-to-extract-a-value-from-a-field-with-spaces.html). But assuming this is a one-off query, I think that you can probably get away with a simple (albeit less efficient) query like the following:

```
index=myIndex "My tool is too picky and has a hard time"
```

The use of quotation marks in the above example query will perform a text-based search for your needed string. This query won't be as efficient as a field-only search would be, but it should get the job done.

Comment: Actually that is not the string I'm searching for. I want to extract all the value for the field HelloSample. It is not always the same string. It is different all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the ability to modify your `props.conf` to extract the field correctly, this `rex` will pull it (presuming it's at the end of the event):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp
| rex field=_raw "HelloSample\=(?<HelloSample>.+)"
```

If your test is somewhere else in the event, we'll need to know what kind of delimeters exist to refine the above regex